# Comparing and eliminating elements of vectors in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have two vectors

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, 6, NA, NA, 10, 11, 12, NA, NA, 13)

y <- c(14, 15, 16, 17, 18 ,19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 ,27)
```

They have both length of 14. I want remove NAs from x and the value that corresponds to it in y. And obtain x and y as equal lengths.

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
 for (j in 1:length(y)) {
   if(is.na(x[, i]==y[, j))
   x <- x[-which(x %n% y)]
 }
}
```

But it doesn't give what I want. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I read the comments above, do you want to plot x and y without NAs?
If so,you can just plot it,R will not give any warnings or error indication.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, 6, NA, NA, 10, 11, 12, NA, NA, 13)
y <- c(14, 15, 16, 17, 18 ,19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 ,27)
plot(x,y)
```

[image: plot(x,y) does not hava problem.]
If you need to remove NAs from x and remove the corresponding values in y,you can combine `x` and `y` into a `data.frame`,then use na.omit() to deal with the `new dataframe`,finally,you can plot it.Ths codes as followed:

```
df2 <- na.omit(data.frame(x,y))
plot(y~x,df2)
```

**OR**:you can use the index to sovle it.
is.na is a function help you detect which is NA.
Finding the NA position in vector x us is.na(),

then remove the corresponding values in y

last,change the value in x.The code as follows:

```
y <- y[!is.na(x)]
x <- x[!is.na(x)]
```

**Notice**:the order cannot be changed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the question is asking: this would replace the NA values in `x` with the corresponding values in `y`.

Comment: @MichaelVeale Yes,previously,I think Emily565 want to get this results.

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- x[!is.na(x)]    
y <- y[!is.na(x)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using R markdown and asked this question to plot my actual data but it gives error incorrect number of dimensions still. Am I doing anything else wrong?

Comment: That would be difficult to predict based on the given data. This would just remove `NA` values from `x` and corresponding values from `y`

Comment: In my actual data, x and y has length of 79. x is a vector with NAs and y is a matrix with 3 columns. I have a selectInput for the column choice.

Comment: so `y` is 79 X 3 matrix ? Can you share the actual `x` and `y` data ?

Comment: yes, I have a 79 X 3 matrix. According to the user's column choice( y ), it should plot x and y. x has length of 79 with NAs

Comment: `y <- mat$y[!is.na(x)]` is this what you want? where `mat` is your matrix.

Comment: selectInput("mat",  ....., choices = c( a, y, b), .. )   and ı have x as a vector.  when the user make choice let's say y, it should remove NA values from x and the value that corresponds to it in y. so the elements of both x and y are decreased from 79.   plot(input$y,  x,   .......)

Comment: If you're trying to remove rows that have NAs in (if you could also combine your data into a single matrix or data frame), are you aware of the `complete.cases` function?

Comment: in which variable is the value stored which the user has selected? (either a, y or b)

Comment: a, y, b all have NA values in different rows. the one the user selects is the variable that will be eliminated and plotted with x

Comment: Try assigning this value to `y` `y <- input[!is.na(input[mat]), mat]` and then `plot(x, y)`

Comment: how can ı rewrite it with not specifying any column like y, like any of them could it be because it is an input from the user. shouldn't ı write it in a for loop ?

Comment: how do you come to know what the user has selected ? (a, b or y) There must be some variable where the value gets stored after the user selects his option. Which is that variable?

Comment: okey, thanks a lot